# Want to change prefix of values in mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql-workbench

I have millions of data in my database table customer. In that, I have the id_token attribute which has value like cus00001 format now I want to change it to ank00001.

What will be the query in rails or mysql to do it for all the data in the database?

Comment: Hi.. Please consider posting any attempt to solve the problem that was already made or any ideas that were in consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple update query using [REPLACE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) function:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id_token` = REPLACE(`id_token`, 'ank', 'cus');
```